# Connect references (Tools>References) with VBA code (macros)

Tags: vba, reference, connect

I want to programmatically connect some references to my VBA project using VBA code, i.e. without manually setting references using Tools>References. Is this possible?  For example Microsoft office 12.0 Object library.

Answer (score 9):

You do not mention an Office application. In MS Access, you can use:

```
ReferenceFromFile "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\MSO.DLL"
```

That is, give the full path for the reference you wish to add.

From: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Add,_Remove,_Check_References

Similarly, in Excel:

```
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\MSO.DLL"
```

To list references in Excel:
    Dim ref As Reference

```
For Each ref In ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.References
    Debug.Print ref.Description; " -- "; ref.FullPath
Next
```

This returns the following on my machine on one particular workbook:

```
Visual Basic For Applications -- C:\PROGRA~1\COMMON~1\MICROS~1\VBA\VBA7\VBE7.DLL
Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library -- C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE
OLE Automation -- C:\Windows\system32\stdole2.tlb
Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library -- C:\Windows\system32\FM20.DLL
Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.0 Library -- C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\ado\msado15.dll
Microsoft XML, v6.0 -- C:\Windows\System32\msxml6.dll
Microsoft Office 14.0 Access database engine Object Library -- C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\ACEDAO.DLL
Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3 -- C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VBA\VBA6\VBE6EXT.OLB
Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library -- C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\MSO.DLL
```

Comment: You need to find out the full paths. See additional notes.

Answer (score 4):

Making references to the full path is fraught with danger and will cause you problems when the code is used on different computers or in different versions.

Far better to use the GUID which in most (but not all instances) remains the same for different versions of an application.

This is helpful especially if you've written code for say Excel 2010 that needs to be used in both Excel 2010 and Excel 2013.

Comment: Here you can find solutions and discussion about adding references by GUID: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879825/how-to-add-a-reference-programmatically-using-vba).

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternate location where the MSO.dll file can be found:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\oFFICE11

Just set the Tool > References >Browse to the above path and locate MSO.dll

Comment: Tested for MS Access 2010 64 bit case