# How to add a new item to a project with just code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, wizard

I've created a custom wizard that allows developers in Visual Studio to be presented with a list of data sets from a database.  The next step is to add an instance of one of the custom classes I've created based off of which data set they choose.  Is there a way to simulate the process of right clicking the solution in the solution explorer, selecting add and new item? (or the same thing through the project drop down).

basically the "adding project items" step, in case i've been unclear:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384482(v=vs.90).aspx

EDIT: I'm in Visual Studio 2012

Comment: im not sure i understand your question correctly. but if you wanted to add an item to the solution explorer ( treeview ) you could follow the same logic as I did in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957334/trying-to-open-the-workbook-in-separate-instance/16959325#16959325) <- look at CreateAModule Sub. You would need to translate this to C# though but that should not be a problem really

Comment: that looks promising, thanks a lot that's exactly what i was looking for! i'm going to translate it and implement it tomorrow so i'll let you know!