# VBA Missing Reference Causes Others to not load

Tags: excel, vba

I Have 2 VBA Macros in an Excel.  Macro 1 copies some values from another Excel file.  Macro 2 requests some values from Bloomberg.  Macro 1 requires a reference to "Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library", and Macro 2 requires a reference to the "Bloomberg Data Type Library" to be added.

I would like it so that users can run Macro 1 even when on a machine without the Bloomberg Excel API installed.  However when I try to run Macro 1 I get to this line:

```
Set XL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

below and get the following error:

```
 "Cant Find Project or Library"
```

It seems like since it can not find the "Bloomberg Data Type Library" reference it is not loading the "Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library" either.

Everything works as expected on a machine with the Bloomberg Excel API installed.

Comment: You should look in to late binding, that way you can do a bit of error checking and running only the proper code: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245115

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879825/how-to-add-a-reference-programmatically-vba-excel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the same file to work on both machines, first remove the reference to BBG in VBA Editor -> Tools -> References. Then in your code do something like that:

```
On Error Resume Next ' turn off errors
Set XL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set BBG = CreateObject("BBGName")

If Not IsEmpty(BBG) Then
    ' Do work with BBG

End If
On Error GoTo 0 ' turn on errors
```

That will allow you to use BBG macro only when BBG library is present, without throwing an error if it is not.

Comment: This worked. The hard part was figuring out the name I needed to pass.  For the other the string you have to pass to get BLP_DATA_CTRLLib.BlpData is GetObject("Bloomberg.Data")

Comment: Yeah, to know the name is sometimes the hardest thing. Cool that this has worked!