# Use a function of an ATL library in a vbasic macro in Excel

Tags: excel, atl, vba

I succeed to create a ATL library in c++ which does some operation and gives back solutions. So I have all the functions in excel by using automation. Now I would like to create a macro which could do all the functions in the right order and after that maybe associating a button to it.
So I've written this macro:

```
Sub Macro_test()

 Dim r As Integer

 r = setValInput(Range("F21"), Range("G21"))
 r = initializeCalculation()
 Range("C24") = r
 r = getResult("C21")


End Sub
```

If i build this Excel says the function setValInput isn't definite. The class of ATL is named OPclass, maybe have I to do something with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create object using [`CreateObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220083%28v=office.11%29.aspx) method. The argument is the `ProgID` value you provided to C++ ATL wizard when you created the COM class, or/and you can look it up in the project `.RGS` files.

Code snippet:

```
   Set MyServer = CreateObject("ProgettoOPserver")
   MyServer.setValInput(Range("F21"), Range("G21"))
```

Methods and properties on the ATL class exposed through implemented interface will be automatically available to your VBA script code.

Another option is to first add a reference to the external COM server (ATL based library) and instead of `CreateObject` you would be able to use [`New`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77s47661.aspx) operator. See more on this: [How to add a reference programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879825/how-to-add-a-reference-programmatically-vba-excel). The advantage is that you will be able to see the available methods in Object Browser.

Comment: Thanks. I have do it, the ProgID is 'ProgettoOPserver' so i have to write CreateObject("ProgettoOPserver") ?? I tried it but continues to say function not definite. Have I to write function with class identifier? In example Web.getResults?

Comment: I update the code snippet. From this end it's well set, further questions are for the other side - the ATL/C++ implementation.

Answer (score 0):

A method that's a member of a class object needs to be called from an instance of the class object.  As you have already created `OPClass` module which presumably contains the method `setValInput`, try something like:

```
Dim op as New OPClass
Debug.Print op.setValInput(Range("F21"),Range("G21"))
```

This assumes you have elsewhere created the object, per Roman's answer.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to do it with the name of class and als the ProgID, but says type not definite!

Comment: Wait, I don't understand, I have to create the object as shown by Roman and after declare with Dim OPCLASS?

Comment: Well I'm not sure what your class object is/does so it's hard for me to say. anyhow it looks like Roman's suggestion solved your problem, cheers!