# Adding a created excel add-in

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I have created a VB add-in for excel with the below code. However, when I open a new excel workbook and attempt to add the reference to the newly created dll, I get an error: "Can't add a reference to the specified path." I am using Excel 2010 on a 32 bit machine. The add-in was created with Visual Studio 2010.

```
Public Class Utils

    '!Deletes old reference and adds new reference. Must be used when switching to new machine. 
    Function addReference() As Boolean
        If Dir("C:\refname.dll") <> "" Then
            Dim ref
            For Each ref In Application.ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References
                If ref.name = "refname" Then
                    Application.ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.Remove(ref)
                End If
            Next
            Application.ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile("C:\refname.dll")
            addReference = True
        Else
            addReference = False
        End If
    End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Option Explicit

    Sub AddReference()
        Dim VBAEditor As VBIDE.VBE
    Dim vbProj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim chkRef As Reference
    Dim BoolExists As Boolean

    Set VBAEditor = Application.VBE
    Set vbProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject

    '~~> Check if reference is already added
    For Each ref In vbProj.References
        If ref.Name = "refname" Then
            BoolExists = True
            GoTo CleanUp
        End If
    Next

    vbProj.References.AddFromFile "C:\WINDOWS\system32\refname.dll\3"

CleanUp:
    If BoolExists = True Then
        MsgBox "Reference already exists"
    Else
        MsgBox "Reference Added Successfully"
    End If

    Set vbProj = Nothing
    Set VBAEditor = Nothing
End Sub
```

I got this code from: [How to add a reference programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879825/how-to-add-a-reference-programmatically-vba-excel)

Comment: The issue isn't with the code itself. If I use the code directly in VBA it works fine. I am not getting any compile errors either. I cannot add the reference to my newly created DLL/Add-In once I build the project. I probably chose a confusing method for this question.... The code could be 'Hello World!' and I'd still have the same issue. I hope that clarifies it a bit.