# vba: regex, remove all but cell reference row references from formula strings

Tags: regex, vba, excel

In VBA I am trying to build a generalized function that turn strings like these:

a) `=IFERROR(PERCENTRANK($FU$23:$FU$2515,FU24,3)*100,FY$17)`

b) `=IF(FZ$16=(BDP($C24,FZ$18,FZ$19,"EQY_FUND_CRNCY",FX)),FZ$17,IF($B24="","",BDP($C24,FZ$18,FZ$19,"EQY_FUND_CRNCY",FX)))`

c) `=IF(ISNUMBER(FU24),TRUNC((((COUNTIF($J$23:$J$2515,$J24)-(SUMPRODUCT(($J$23:$J$2515=$J24)*(FU24<FU$23:FU$2515))))/COUNTIF($J$23:$J$2515,$J24)))*100,2),FX$17)`

d) `=IFERROR(PERCENTRANK(EO$23:EO$2515,EO24,3)*(-100)+100,ET$17)`

e) `=BDP($C24,EH$18,EH$19,"EQY_FUND_CRNCY",FX)`

Into these:

a) `23 2515 24 17`

b) `16 24 18 19 17 24 24 18 19`

c) `24 23 2515 24 23 2515 24 24 23 2515 23 2515 24 17`

d) `23 2515 24 17`

e) `24 18 19`

In other words, remove everything except cell reference rows and separate them with spaces (or some other deliminator) so I can `VBA.split(x," ")` them later.

Notes:

1. Numbers that aren't part of a cell references are removed.
2. To use this function you must have the regular expression library.  If the code below doesn't work for you include the library: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/818802. (Side note: if you know how to include the library in the code without having to follow those instructions, please share.)
3. The list of formulas in this example is just an example. I am looking for a generalized solution.
4. I built this little test sub that might be helpful (IT DOESN'T DO WHAT I WANT):

   ```
   Sub test()

   Dim s As String
   s = "=IFERROR(PERCENTRANK($FU$23:$FU$2515,FU24,3)*100,FY$17)"
   Dim s2 As String
   Dim s3 As String
   Dim s1 As String
   Static re As RegExp
   If re Is Nothing Then Set re = New RegExp
   re.IgnoreCase = True
   re.Global = True
   re.Pattern = "[$]"
   s1 = re.Replace(s, "")
   re.Pattern = "[^A-Z0-9 ]"
   s2 = re.Replace(s1, " ")
   re.Pattern = "[^0-9]"
   s3 = re.Replace(s2, " ")
   Debug.Print s3
   End Sub
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub test()

    Dim s As String, matches, m

    s = "=IFERROR(PERCENTRANK($FU$23:$FU$2515,FU24,3)*100,FY$17)"

    Static re As Object 
        If re Is Nothing Then

            Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp") 'late binding

            re.IgnoreCase = True
            re.Global = True
            re.Pattern = "[A-Z]+\$?(\d+)"
        End If

    Set matches = re.Execute(s)

    If matches.Count > 0 Then
        For Each m In matches
            Debug.Print m.SubMatches(0)
        Next m
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks. Just curious if there is a way to include the reference via code so I can use RegExp without including it manually? The Dim's in this link error out for me: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879825/how-to-add-a-reference-programmatically-vba-excel)

Comment: Sorry - missed that declaration. Fixed now