# Is it possible to access VBA code in outlook using VBA in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to connect several macros from Outlook and Excel. One of the functions needs to access vba code from the other program and analyse it. It was quite easy to acces VBA code in Excel from Outlook, for example:

```
Set WB = Workbooks.Open(Address)
Set codeAddress = WB.VBProject.VBComponents(1).codemodule
```

But I wonder how to access Outlook macros from Excel. I tried to analyse Outlook application properties through watch window, but I hadn't find anything appropriate.
Stackoverflow, have you got any ideas?

Comment: yes it is possible, you might need to include some reference library to do it. Check out this link http://www.dicks-clicks.com/excel/olBinding.htm

Comment: As I know, this library should be turned on manually, so the code will be rooted to my computer only =( Is there other ways (like I did in Excel)?

Comment: You can turn on automatically a reference to a library. Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879825/how-to-add-a-reference-programmatically-in-excel-vba

Comment: What exactly do you need to implement? What is the final goal of such manipulations?

Answer (score 2):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any property or method for that. The VBAProject.otm file contains all Outlook VBA macros.

> All Outlook macros are stored in a single file named VbaProject.otm in the user's %appdata%\Microsoft\Outlook folder, which will be a hidden folder on most systems.