# Adding reference to VBA

Tags: vba, reference, project

I am trying to automatically add a reference while running a sub. 
But I get **"User defined-type not defined**" for **project As VBAProject**
What's wrong?

```
  Sub tester()

    Dim SolverPath As String
    SolverPath = Application.LibraryPath & "\SOLVER\SOLVER.XLA"

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Dim project As VBAProject
    project = wb.VBProject

    wb.project.References.AddFromFile SolverPath

End Sub
```

Comment: See here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879825/how-to-add-a-reference-programmatically-in-excel-vba

Answer (score 0):

`VBAProject` is actually a special type of library, not a variable type. If you hit `F2` to bring up the Object Browser, you can select it from the library dropdown. So you can't create variables of type `VBAProject`. However, it's not necessary to, nor for `ThisWorkbook`, unless you just want a shorter alias. Just use the workbook's `VBProject` property to gain access to the current project instance and add/remove components. Your code could be simplified to:

```
Sub tester()

    Dim SolverPath As String
    SolverPath = Application.LibraryPath & "\SOLVER\SOLVER.XLA"

    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromFile SolverPath

End Sub
```