# Excel VBA late bind Microsoft DAO 3.6 object library

Tags: excel, vba, dao, late-binding

Can anybody post a snippet on how to create a reference to Microsoft DAO 3.6 object library from Excel 2007?

I gather I need to use the CreateObject method but I can't find anything online concerning the right parameters to reference DAO 3.6 specifically.

I need to late bind as I won't be able to manually set references on each PC using the file.

Many thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding the reference by vba?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879825/how-to-add-a-reference-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

Thes best place to learn about DAO is Microsoft's Developer Network.  There is a lot of [documentation on the subject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820966.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

VBA supports three data access technologies.  [DAO, ADO and RDO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa261340(v=vs.60).aspx).  Of these Microsoft recommend you use ADO, the newer of the three.

I've been trying to write a late bound Excel DAO example, but I've run into a little trouble.  I've only been able to get an early bound approach working.

```
Sub ExampleEarly()
    Dim DB As DAO.database
   Dim RS As DAO.Recordset


    ' Connect to Excel spreadsheet and read from tab called VA.
    Set DB = OpenDatabase("C:\Example\ExcelFile.xls", False, True, "Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes")
    Set RS = DB.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [VA$]")

'Close the recordset
    RS.Close    
    DB.Close
    Set RS = Nothing    
    Set DB = Nothing
End Sub
```

ADO can be late bound like so:

```
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs AS Object

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs= CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
```

Answer (score 1):

For DAO late binding. Not fully tested compatibility if you use ADO in your code, but it works so far in my projects.

```
Dim db As Object  'late binding without reference, seems to work, but might cause trouble, not tested
Dim tbl As Object

Dim dbe As Object
Set dbe = CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine.120")  'depends on win version!


Set db = dbe.OpenDatabase(file)
Set tbl = db.TableDefs("CAPEX")
```