# objFso.Drives(strDrive).ShareName does not work on Windows 7

Tags: vba, excel

I have some VBA that opens a spreadsheet template, copies some information into the template and saves it with a new name.  This works fine on a Windows 10 machine but when I run it on a Windows 7 box it falls over at the following line:

```
strShare = objFso.Drives(strDrive).ShareName
```

Trying to work out if it's Windows 7 or are there some references that I need tick in order to get this to run?

Comment: What exactly does "falls over" mean? If you get an error, what is it?

Comment: Sorry, yes the code throws an exception: Run-Time Error 5 invalid call or argument

Comment: Do you have a reference set to the scripting runtime?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what that means?

Comment: Tools - References in the VB Editor. Are you sure the drive exists on the 7 box? Is it a mapped drive or local?

Comment: Hi Rory,  Another user (remote to my location) is using the tool on the windows 7 machine.  Is there a set of references that they need enabled to have the tool work do you think?

Comment: References are saved with the workbook. Which ones are checked when you view the references in the file?

Comment: The only difference in references between the windows 7 and windows 10 version is windows 7 is using 'Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library' and windows 10 is using 'Microsoft Office 15.0 Object Library'. Other than that all the references are the same.  Would this cause the problem?

Comment: No. Which references are checked? Also what is the value of `strDrive` when the error occurs?

Comment: References checked: Visual Basic for Applications, Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library, OLE Automation, Microsoft Office 15.0 Object Library, Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library, Microsoft Scripting Runtime.  The person running the code on the wondows 7 box is away, but will post as soon as I can find out that the strDrive value is.

Answer (score 0):

You try to use`Office 15.0 Object Library`reference with`Office 14.0 Object Library`installed, what causes all referenced libs to fail loading (you can't use older lib with newer ref, just opposite).

3 Options:

1. (recommended) Use`Late-Binding`see my answer on [Updating Microsoft 2010 VBA Object Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51313215/9439330).
   e.g.:

```vb
Dim objFso as Object
Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystem")
```

2. If you need`Early-Binding`for somewhat reason, reference the oldest library version you want to support, as e.g.`Office 14.0 Object Library`reference works with`Office 15`installed (newer lib with older ref), but that can fail if you accidentially use the wrong reference.
3. Use vba to [add a reference programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879825/how-to-add-a-reference-programmatically)