# wdReplaceAll is Empty

Tags: vba, ms-word

Currently I am using a for loop to lay down 4 rounds of data, I was hoping to have it replace all that are corresponding to the current word template, but doing this all in excel VBA
Unfortunately the code that I am not using is no working and the wdReplaceAll = Empty.

I've tried resetting parameters and even having        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll changed to        .Execute Replace:=1. But Nothing in my word document is being replaced

```
Dim WordApp As Object
Dim DocFileName As String
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    DocFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Word\TCAP Update.docx"
    WordApp.Documents.Open DocFileName

For i = 1 To TCAPCount

        Summary(i) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
        Key(i) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value
        Updated(i) = Format(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value, "MM/DD/YYYY")
        Cells.Find(what:="NEAR DATE", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True).Activate
        ColorInd = ActiveCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        Do Until ActiveCell.Value <> "NEAR DATE" And ActiveCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = ColorInd
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        Loop
        ActualDate(i) = Format(ActiveCell.Value, "MM/DD/YYYY")
        ActualDateNam(i) = Range(Split(ActiveCell(1).Address(1, 0), "$")(0) & "1").Value
        Range(SEMCol & ActiveCell.Row).Select

        Do
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            If ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
                'keep looking
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    Next i    

    If TCAPCount > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Please take this time to create " & TCAPCount & " extra TCAP Templates for " & SEM
        WordApp.Visible = True
        MsgBox "When you are ready to proceed please select OK"
    End If

For i = 1 To TCAPCount
    With WordApp.Selection.Find
        .Text = "Key " & (i)
        .Replacement.Text = Key(i)
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        .Text = "Summary " & (i)
        .Replacement.Text = Summary(i)
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        .Text = "ActualDate " & (i)
        .Replacement.Text = ActualDate(i)
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        .Text = "ActualDateNam " & (i)
        .Replacement.Text = ActualDateNam(i)
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        .Text = "Updated " & (i)
        .Replacement.Text = Updated(i)
          .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
Next i
```

I am hoping to replace
Key 1 | Summary 1
ActualDateNam 1– ActualDate 1
Last Update: Updated 1
Key 2 | Summary 2
ActualDateNam 2– ActualDate 2
Last Update: Updated 2
Key 3 | Summary 3
ActualDateNam 3– ActualDate 3
Last Update: Updated 3
Key 4 | Summary 4
ActualDateNam 4– ActualDate 4
Last Update: Updated 4

with it's corresponding data ie i=1  and Key (i) = "Apples", then Key 1 will be replaced as "Apples".

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask], then improve formatting of your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Option Explicit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139321/how-do-i-force-vba-access-to-require-variables-to-be-defined/1139522#1139522), vba compiler would complain about not knowing`wdReplaceAll`as you use [late-bound word object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51311025/updating-microsoft-2010-vba-object-libraries/51313215#51313215), what prevents you using its enums.

You tried to fix that, but who told you that`wdReplaceAll = 1`?

If you read the docs you see [wdReplaceAll = 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdreplace?view=word-pia)