# Run Excel Solver from Macro on any computer

Tags: vba, excel

I have a coursework half of which is in excel. I added a bonus functionality using macros called by a button. However, I found that my teacher would have to go through all the settings I had to do in order to run the macros - adding Solver to excel and then referencing it in VBA. Is it possible to do all of that in the macros so that my teacher could just click the button and see the result? Thank you!

Comment: Allowing a VBA project add references programmatically requires special trust granting which is even worse. [You can do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9880276/11683), but you should not.

Comment: Thanks GSerg! You could write it as an answer so that I could accept it...

Comment: It's not okay to post a link to an existing question as an answer. If https://stackoverflow.com/a/9880276/11683 answers your question I would rather close as duplicate.