# VBA - Auto check/uncheck microsoft script run time

Tags: vba, excel, vbide

I had the following function that auto add `Microsoft Script Runtime` Reference to the Reference list. However, if the user already had included `Microsoft script runtime`, it will show error `Name conflicts with existing module,project, object library`.

How do I set an condition that auto adds `Microsoft script runtime` if it is not included in the reference and do nothing if it has already being added?

```
Private Function AddScriptingLibrary() As Boolean

Const GUID As String = "{420B2830-E718-11CF-893D-00A0C9054228}"

On Error GoTo errHandler
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid GUID, 1, 0
AddScriptingLibrary = True
Exit Function
errHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description

End Function
```

Comment: Did you see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879825/how-to-add-a-reference-programmatically/9880276#9880276)?

Comment: @SiddharthRout After a second though, I think it does not solve my problem since it will add another Reference

Comment: It will not add another reference if you check for it before :)

Comment: Why would you need code to check if the reference is set in its own workbook? The reference is saved with the workbook so unless you're expecting a user to go in and *uncheck* it for some reason, it makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to enumerate the references of the project first, in order to check if the reference is already present.

I've added a reference to **Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3**

```
Option Explicit

Function AddScriptingLibrary()

    Const GUID_Scripting = "{420B2830-E718-11CF-893D-00A0C9054228}"

    Dim proj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim ref As VBIDE.Reference
    Dim ScriptingLibraryIsReferenced As Boolean

    Set proj = ThisWorkbook.VBProject

    For Each ref In proj.References
      If ref.GUID = GUID_Scripting Then
          ScriptingLibraryIsReferenced = True
          AddScriptingLibrary = True
          Exit Function
      End If
    Next ref

    If Not ScriptingLibraryIsReferenced Then
        On Error GoTo errHandler
        proj.References.AddFromGuid GUID_Scripting, 1, 0
        AddScriptingLibrary = True
        Exit Function

errHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
      End If

End Function
```

**EDIT** this does the same, but without the early-bound reference to Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility 5.3 reference:

```
Option Explicit

Function AddScriptingLibrary()

    Const GUID_Scripting = "{420B2830-E718-11CF-893D-00A0C9054228}"

    Dim proj As Object 'VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim ref As Object 'VBIDE.Reference
    Dim ScriptingLibraryIsReferenced As Boolean

    Set proj = ThisWorkbook.VBProject

    For Each ref In proj.References
      If ref.GUID = GUID_Scripting Then
          ScriptingLibraryIsReferenced = True
          AddScriptingLibrary = True
          Exit Function
      End If
    Next ref

    If Not ScriptingLibraryIsReferenced Then
        On Error GoTo errHandler
        proj.References.AddFromGuid GUID_Scripting, 1, 0
        AddScriptingLibrary = True
        Exit Function

errHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
      End If

End Function
```

But then, if you're happy with the down-sides of late-bound code, you don't even need the reference to `Scripting.Runtime`, because you can just use:

```
Option Explicit

Sub PrintDriveCount()

    Dim FSO As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'Print the number of drives in the FileSystemObject
    Debug.Print FSO.Drives.Count

End Function
```

Comment: This certainly answers the question, but since there is a need to add another reference manually, I guess we are back to the initial problem.
I feel like replacing `VBIDE.VBProject` and `VBIDE.Reference` by `Object` would probably be more appropriate.

Comment: Sorry I new to this, learning and using code on the spot and not really sure about how it works. I am able to understand the concept of the codes. I will pass the excel workbook to other users as well. Do they have to add the reference to **Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3** as well? Or when I pass the workbook to them, it is already added, since it is added by me.

Comment: Adding the reference isn't necessary, but then neither is adding the reference to Scripting Runtime. All of the objects can be used late-bound, but it will be slower, you won't get design-time compiliation, or Intellisense.

Comment: @DecimalTurn Thanks, by applying ThunderFrame's answer and your suggestion it works out fine. I unchecked the `Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3` and it looks good.