# How can I permanently save VBA references

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

We have several VBA excel and word files that we use as templates in a shared network.

The code needs to have an external library as a reference. Is there any way to save the template with this reference as a default and not having to select it every time we want to run the macros?

Comment: What kind of external library? Where is it saved? Have you tried saving it in a shared location in the network? Or have you tried adding it using VBA (the VBE object model, AddReferenceFromFile)?

Comment: its an executable file. It is saved in everyone's C: drive. I tried to save it in a shared location, but when I go tools/references/browse / this shared folder the library is not loaded, because it already exists in the list of the libraries(of course not selected and its the one located on my c:drive) .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879825/how-to-add-a-reference-programmatically

Comment: thanks! but from the solutions I still have to manually check the Microsoft Visual Basic for applications extensibility library...