# How to remove reference from VBA

Tags: excel, vba

My Excel file has the following references:

[image: LINK HERE]

I think the reference to Shockwave flash is causing errors to some users. So I removed it manually from the GUID, but it gets added automatically again after opening Excel.

How do I remove it?

And how do I find if/where it is being used?

Thank you

Comment: Check your code. There must be something which is adding reference? Something like [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879825/how-to-add-a-reference-programmatically/9880276#9880276) maybe?

Comment: Thank you, I've searched all the code to find AddFromFile or AddFromGuid, but nothing. The reference appears again when I reopen the file..

Comment: Do you have any Shockwave objects embedded in the workbook anywhere?

Comment: @Rory yes, a shockwave video. I just found it!