# Add and remove Word 16.0 Reference

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, reference

I need to create 2 buttons on excel, one to add the reference Microsoft Word 16.0 object library, another one to remove the reference. Can you help me with the VBA code please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879825/how-to-add-a-reference-programmatically-using-vba TLDR: use late binding instead and save the headache.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42228424/14608750) great answer from the same post has a very useful function `DebugPrintExistingRefs` that will help you find the GUID of the Word 16.0 object library. Add the reference manually, run the `DebugPrintExistingRefs` and then look at the Immediate Window for the GUID.